# php regex to match template tags

Tags: php, regex

I have a some template tags in a PHP file that I can't seem to match with a regular expression. Actually, what I'm using I've made work before but I can't make it work this time. All the template tags will look like this `{$EXAMPLE}`, two squigglies surrounding a dollar sign followed by anything. Actually, the word example will always be uppercase and may contain underscores or dashes, but that part isn't really necessary. What I have already is this:

Template file:

```
{$HEADER}
{$MENU}
{$BODY}
{$FOOTER}
```

PHP file:

```
$template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE);
preg_match_all('^{$.*}^U', $template, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

where `var_dump` outputs an empty array.

Comment: What awful `^` [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) you picked there? ... The problem is, that you didn't escape the `$`. It is a [metacharcter](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) in regex: anchor for end of line/string. To match a literal `$` it must be escaped as `\$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the curly braces and the dollar sign are [meta-characters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php), you need to escape them with backslashes. Change your regular expression from `^{$.*}^U` to `^\\{\\$.*\\}^U` and your code will work perfectly.

Comment: quick note, each of these are picking up each instance of the tag in the file, which is useful sometimes and sometimes not, so I'm just using array_unique on results when I don't need duplicate tags picked up and it's working perfectly, definitely better than what I had

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$template = file_get_contents(TEMPLATE);
preg_match_all('/^(\{\$.*\})^U/', $template, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

See live demo here: http://rubular.com/r/52kKX0dIdl

Comment: works, thank you, first working answer I'm going to say is solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
preg_match_all('~{\$[^}]+}~', $template, $matches); // negated character class + greedy quantifier
```

or

```
preg_match_all('~{\$[A-Z_-]+}~', $template, $matches); // follows your description
```